# Как упростить генерацию name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

инпутов может быть большое количество с разным **name**

речь о двух строках

```
elem.find('input[name="block"]').attr('name', 'block'+$('.item').length++)
 
elem.find('input[name="test"]').attr('name', 'test'+$('.item').length++)
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
  let elem = $('.item.copy').clone();
  elem.removeAttr('style');
  elem.removeClass('copy');
  elem.find('input[name="block"]').attr('name', 'block' + $('.item').length++)
  elem.find('input[name="test"]').attr('name', 'test' + $('.item').length++)
  $('.holder').append(elem);
})
```

```css
.holder {
  counter-reset: number;
  position: relative;
}

p::after {
  position: absolute;
  counter-increment: number;
  content: counter(number);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
  <div class="item">
    <p>item</p>
    <input type="text" name="block">
    <input type="text" name="test">
  </div>
  <div class="item copy" style='display: none'>
    <p> item</p>
    <input type="text" name="block">
    <input type="text" name="test">
  </div>
  <!-- то что хочу получить после склонирования
   <div class="item copy" style='display: none'>
    <p>2 item</p>
    <input type="text" name="block2">
  </div>
  ид
  -->
</div>

<button id="btn">
  склонировать элемент
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проще верстку перенести в JS, чем клонировать что-то и заменять лишнее.

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  let idx = $(".item").length + 1;
  let tpl = `<div class="item">
              <p>item</p>
              <input type="text" name="block${idx}"/>
              <input type="text" name="name${idx}"/>
             </div>`;
  $('.holder').append($(tpl));
})
```

```css
.holder {
   counter-reset: number;
   position: relative;
 }

 p::after {
   position: absolute;
   counter-increment: number;
   content: counter(number);

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
  <div class="item">
    <p>item</p>
    <input type="text" name="block">
    <input type="text" name="test">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">
  склонировать элемент
</button>
```

также стоит обратить внимание, что скорее более удобным вариантом хранения данных будет не `block1/name1` а в виде массива `data[1][name]/data[1][block]`